# Binary R heatmap still displays gradient

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to plot a heatmap for a matrix of binary data (11 x ~1500) in R.

```
heatmap(y, col = hmcols);
```

the matrix 'y' looks like this

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1
[2,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     0     0     1     1 ...etc...
```

I'm using the default distance and clustering functions, but for some reason my heatmap displays a gradient of color. I've tried to use the binary distance function as well, although a similar gradied occurs. Is this a lack of similarity in samples due to the distance between each sample? Here is an image of the heatmap:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jz1r41lhnrkisvz/Rplots.pdf

I feel like this is due to my lack of understanding of exactly how the default distance and clustering functions reorder data. How can I interpret these results?

Comment: You probably just need to read `?heatmap` carefully. Look at the `scale` argument.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @Joran point out, the `scale` argument is the one to go with:

(Note: I reduced dimensionality and generated random data since you did not provide your full set)

The colors are chosen by `col`, if you want simple black and white you can do `col = c("black", "white")`, but you can also make things more interesting:

```
x <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 15*15, replace = TRUE), nrow = 15)
heatmap(x, scale = "none", Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = cm.colors(2), main = "HeatMap Example")
```

[image]

Comment: @lennart does this answer your question? If so please accept, if not, how can I improve it?

Comment: Hi mlegge, I know it is very late to ask.. but plz try to clarify my doubt. If we want row names on top and column names in right..what are the modifications to do in code?

Comment: @ThulasiR you'd have to create a new function that writes them differently change this line `axis(1, 1L:nc, labels = labCol, las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0, cex.axis = cexCol)` to this: `axis(3, 1L:nc, labels = labCol, las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0, cex.axis = cexCol)`

Comment: Again sorry for delay in reply.. Thank you for explanation

Comment: This gives a reversed ordering for the rows --- can you fix that?

Comment: @Ben-ReinstateMonica yes, add the `revC = TRUE` argument.